# Solving time in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve an SOCP in MATLAB using CVX. After solving it, in the workspace, the time to solve it is written as cvx_cputime=48.6250, while in the command window, it is written Total CPU time (secs) = 5.04.
Can anyone please explain what is the difference between the two? I am not able to find it anywhere. And which one should I consider as the time to solve the problem?

Comment: I believe that `cvx_cputime` will count how much "cpu time" will have taken, i.e. how much time would have it taken for 1 cpu to do it. Do you have a 10 core CPU?

Comment: @AnderBiguri 4 cores

Comment: Probably 4 cores with hyperthreading, i.e. 8.